# Any better way to write this small code?

Tags: python, optimization

I'm processing a.CSV file in python which has a floating type field.

This field has to be modified such that it has at least 4 decimal points and max 8 decimal points of precision.

Example:

```
input: 5.15
output: 5.1500

input: -12.129999998
output: -12.12999999
```

What I'm currently doing:

```
#The field to be modifed is present at index 3 in list temp
dotIndex = temp[3].find('.') + 1
latLen = len(temp[3])-1

if (latLen) - (dotIndex) > 8:
    temp[3] = temp[3][0:dotIndex+4]
elif (latLen) - (dotIndex) < 4:
    temp[3] = temp[3][0:latLen] + (4 - (latLen - (dotIndex))) * '0'
```

Is there a better way to write this code to improve performance ?

Comment: just cast `temp[3]` to float and then write it back with something like `print('{:.8f}'.format())`. Checking to see how big it is and buffing it or cutting it is too much work.

Comment: Are you intending to truncate your values, or actually round them? Your second example, if rounded properly, should go to 13.13000000 for example.

Comment: @asongtoruin I'm trying to truncate them.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis Could you please elaborate on the writing back part?

Answer (score 2):

this should work:

```
temp[3] = "{:.4f}".format(float(temp[3]))
```

Considering your comment and the fact you want it truncated, here you go:

```
n = len(temp[3].split('.')[1])
if n < 4:
    temp[3] = "{:.4f}".format(float(temp[3]))
elif n > 8:
    parts = temp[3].split('.')
    temp[3] = parts[0]+"."+parts[1][:4]
```

Comment: A max of 8 point precision should also be allowed. Please check the 2nd input/output example.

Comment: Also, when n>8, can't we just write temp[3] = "{:.8f}".format(float(temp[3]))

Comment: formating a float does round it up
so you can't use this method as you wish to truncate it

Comment: is it answering your expectations ?

Comment: Yes, it does. But apparently, my code (which is written in the question) takes less time to execute somehow....

Answer (score 1):

If you're truncating, not rounding, you could use something like this:

```
def truncate_to_eight(val):
    return '{:.8f}'.format((int(val * 10**8))/(10.0**8))
```

Multiplying by 10 to the power of 8, taking the integer part, and then dividing by 10 to the power 8 gets you the truncation required. Note however, this will always return a value with 8 decimal places - so 5.15 becomes 5.15000000.

You would use this by saying, for example:

```
rounded = truncate_to_eight(temp[3])
```